# How to add third party framework to mobile substrate tweak

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, theos, cydia

I would like to add the iOS AWS framework, specifically S3 functionality, to a Mobile Substrate tweak that I am building. Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work. I have tried adding the following to my Makefile without any success:

```
xxxxx_CFLAGS += -I./External/
```

OR

```
xxxxx_LDFLAGS += -l./External/AWSS3.framework
```

The frameworks, Core and S3 are located in ./External directory. Whatever I try I always get the following error:

```
fatal error: 'AWSS3/AWSS3.h' file not found
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you got the answer?

Comment: Bump for this, Did you manage to get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try coping it to **/Library/Frameworks** and load it from there iOS will automatically search for frameworks in that location

Comment: Excuse me, could I ask, what do you mean about "and load it from there"? Because I put the third party frameworks at /Library/Frameworks, compiles well, but doesn't work when running, can't find why.